# What are props.values in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a project with react, redux and redux-form. Playing with redux-form [shouldValidate](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/525da9e5a60f23e31d376ce630cfb5098aab4248/docs/api/ReduxForm.md#shouldvalidateparams--boolean-optional) function, I wanted to see what was inside props and nextProps. The default implementation of shouldValidate function handles variables props.values. I wonder what those props.values are? Are they a react thing, redux thing or redux-form related? Where could I find documentation about them? As those values are not something I'm by myself adding in anywhere. I consoled them, and they consisted attributes like source and status:

```
source: "FORM"
status: "RECEIVED"
```

Inside the render method of my component, I see no props.values. Only the props I have given to the component myself. But inside the shouldValidate function, there are props.values prop.

EDIT: For those trying to explain basics of props to me:

Do not, I know what props are in react. What I'm asking is what is this particular props.values prop? Where does it come from, as I have not inserted it by myself. Somehow it is related to react, redux and redux-form

Comment: Sry for explaining the basics to you. Could you provide the console logs and where you write them? This could help the community to give an answer. Give us an example of your code and you probably get better help.

Comment: The props.values contained: source: "FORM"
status: "RECEIVED". Also one other property that is found in the root of props too. Those texts I feel like are related to redux and redux-form.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. This are to props of your form component right? If not which component is it?

Comment: yeah they are the props passed to my component. though I didn't know they would include props.values prop. The location of console logging them was inside this shouldValidate function. Inside the render method of my component, I see no props.values. Only the props I have given to the component myself. But inside the shouldValidate function, there are props.values prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm one of the Redux Form maintainers.

The [`shouldValidate` function](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-shouldvalidate-params-boolean-optional-) receives a single parameter `params` which is comprised of the following *documented* keys:

- `values`
- `nextProps`
- `props`
- `initialRender`
- `structure`

`props`/`nextProps` are a combination of props as documented [here](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/Props.md/) + whatever you manually provided to the component (eg `<MyForm customProp="bla" />`).

Even though such prop `values` is available (and is in fact something from Redux Form), please don't rely on it.
As you can see, `values` is undocumented at that page.

Also, there's no need to use something which is undocumented if the documented `params` of `shouldValidate` is equivalent.

<sub>* If you feel like our docs could be improved to declare "special cased props", go ahead and send us a pull request!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You linked the shouldValidate function documentation. The documentation states that values are redux-form specific, and contains all the filed values your form currently has.

Redux-form keeps track of all the input values you put inside a "Field" tag and keeps it in the redux store.

The props are the properties you define for you own "Form" component. Redux-forms wraps it creating a HOC (higher order component). It passes props in shouldValidate for you to access your props. props.values is an internal representation of filed values, which you should not rely on, the representation may change in the future.

Comment: But I'm not talking about the values in that documentation. In that same documentation there are props and nextProps. I consoled what they consisted, and they consisted the props the component receives. But also, it consists props.values, and I'm not by myself giving that prop to the component. So I want to know where it comes from

Comment: The props are the properties you define for you own "Form" component. Redux-forms wraps it creating a HOC (higher order component). It passes props in shouldValidate for you to access your props. props.values is an internal representation of field values, which you should not rely on, the representation may change in the future.

Comment: So you should use the values parameter, not the props.values to access field values. They may be the same today, but may change in the future.

Comment: They have never been the same to me. They are not even close. Also, I know that the props are the props I have defined for my own form component. But I never defined props.values prop. So I wanted to know where did that come from? Who inserted it?